# Failed to find Build Tools revision 25.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I tried setting the build tools version in the project settings to 25.0.0. And also to add the correct apply plugin statement (you'll find it in the screenshot). I've also tried syncing the project with Gradle files although I don't think this issue is related to that.

Basically making sure this is there. I also downloaded and updated the required SDKs. I'll attach the screenshots.

build.gradle file screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ardbH.png

Project Structure Settings > Module
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRR09.png

SDK Info
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4jr.png

Build.gradle file (project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.2"
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: can you please attach the `build.gradle` for the `project` level as well. also, please attach the dependencies in the `app` level `build.gradle`

Comment: attached both of them please check Mohit Ajwani

Comment: Please update your gradle plugin. `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2` in the project level file. This is an old one, maybe build tools 25.0.0 does not support it. Need to check in the release notes. I am pretty sure the latest is more than 3.4.0.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot!

Comment: The problem was solved? If yes, I can write an answer and then you can accept it.

Comment: Yup it did work!

Comment: I added the answer. You can accept it as it solved the problem. Also you can upvote comments since the upvoted comments get listed in the comments section if there are too many comments.

Answer (score 0):

For the  Failed to Find Build Tools Revision 25.0.0 error in android studio first you save your work and close the project.

- Open the SDK Manager and click on "SDK Tools"
- Find the Package 25.0.0 and check if the package is installed or not.
- Intsall the Package or else check if some other package with other version already installed and change the **buildtooolversion** in **build.gradle**

after performing this step run the program again it will work.

If the issue occurs again then try upgrading your buildtoolversion again.

Comment: Thanks! Although I have run into a new error, this did solve the previous problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: I had faced this issue so i solved this way anyway your problem got solved.

Comment: pretty sure `buildtooolversion` isn't an actual property name, could you double check how it's spelled?

Answer (score 0):

You can please update your gradle plugin `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2` in the project level file. This is an old one, maybe build tools `25.0.0` does not support it. Need to check in the release notes. I am pretty sure the latest is more than `3.4.0`.